# I want to install Autodesk eagle but get getting following error

Tags: software-installation

```
./eagle: symbol lookup error: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLX_mesa.so.0: undefined symbol: xcb_dri3_get_supported_modifiers
```

Autodesk eagle requires following dependencies
libc.so.6 with subversion GLIBC_2.14 or higher.

Please Help!!

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version? What is the version of Eagle?

Comment: My ubuntu ver: 20.04             Autodesk  Eagle version:9.6.5

Answer (score 1):

There is some graphics incompatibility of EAGLE and Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

As a workaround run it always with:

```
env LIBGL_ALWAYS_SOFTWARE=1 ./eagle
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a .desktop link

```
[Desktop Entry]  
Type=Application  
Name=Eagle  
Name[de_DE]=Eagle                                                        
Comment=Test the terminal running a command inside it  
Exec=env LIBGL_ALWAYS_SOFTWARE=1 /home/YOUR_PC/eagle-9.6.2/./eagle run  
Icon=/home/YOUR_PC/eagle-9.6./bin/eagle-logo.png  
Categories=Development;  
Terminal=false
```

And eagle start

Comment: This will allow to start eagle by double click on the icon... provided it can start.  What is special in your link to resolve the `symbol lookup error` mentionned?