# Installing libraries in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: libraries

How to download "***libc.so.6 with subversion GLIBC_2.14 or higher***" in Ubuntu 20.04 focal fossa

Comment: This is a real problem with EAGLE, see [answer for the original question](https://askubuntu.com/a/1269395/66509).

Answer (score 2):

This requirement is [already satisfied](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&exact=1&searchon=names&keywords=libc6).

Even Ubuntu 16.04 LTS has GLIBC 2.23.